# can Raspberry pi 5 support external hard disk?

Tags: pi-5

Sorry for the noob question,can raspberry pi 5 run the external usb hard drive with 27W power supply and with 15W power supply?

Comment: your question is unclear ... are you saying that the hard drive has its own power supply?

Comment: No. I have a 2.5 mm, usb 3.0 external hard disk. e.g https://www.amazon.in/dp/B06XDKWLJH?th=1

if i connect this to my pi5, will it(pi5) be able to power the hard disk and run it?

Comment: Probably (but I doubt anyone will guarantee it).  I'm guessing you have the official supply as 5V/5A supplies aren't common AFAICT; apparently *"The total power drawn from the four USB ports on Raspberry Pi 5 is limited by default to a nominal 600mA; this limit is automatically increased to a nominal 1.6A when the USB-C PD Power Supply is detected."* (https://www.sparkfun.com/news/8391)  Not clear from that whether that is any 5A supply or just the official one.  1.6A should be enough for a portable USB 3 harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd care to [read the documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi-5.html#powering-raspberry-pi-5), you wouldn't have to ask.

#### For the 27W "PD" supply:

Yes - it can.  This answer covers the vast majority of what you have referred to in your question as *"external usb hard drive"*(s), **but** it may not cover them all. There is no definitive answer to your question because no one can say what the the current draw limit is for *"external usb hard drive"*(s). And so you may actually have to read the specs for the *"external usb hard drive"* you intend to use to get the definitive answer. Apologies for our abysmal lack of mind-reading skills.  :))

#### For the 15W supply:

The answer to this question [hinges upon](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hinge+on) a statement from the "official documentation":

> ***"the current draw to peripherals will be restricted to 600mA"***
> <sup>Note that this statement applies **only** to the 15W supply.</sup>

And so the answer depends on just how much power your *"external usb hard drive"* draws. Most of the ones I have used with the RPi seem to get by with 600mA, but as @goldilocks said in his comment: ***"no guarantees"***. And so once again, we are forced to put you in the position for having to research/read something for yourself.

Or, you could take this answer to read as follows:

> **If you can find a USB drive that draws less than 600mA - the answer is "Yes" again.**  :))